# bluemix content management for android mobile application

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have been doing a POC for Bluemix Mobile Application Content Manager. I download a sample application for MACM Android SDK and successfully ran it. However, I don't know how to connect to my Bluemix application.

I created below that information that I am not able to understand:

provided API credentials and URLs
API ID: 0000000123
API password: xxxxxxxxxx
Use the Manager credentials and URL to start creating content for your mobile app.

Manager ID: 3344555443333
Manager password: ssssssssss

Our mobile application once lunched app below that user need to input the value,
1.ServerURL  ???
2.ContextRoot ???
3.Tenant ???
4.MACM Library  ??
5.user  ??
6.password  ??

Above that configuration, I need to give the input of my sample application. Please give me some advice.

refer Link : https://github.com/digexp/MACM-SDK-android/blob/master/README.md
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxEK5.jpg)

Android logcat throws the following error messages:

> failed to query item list: status code = -1, message = unexpected end
>   of stream on Connection{macm-rendering.saas.ibmcloud.com:443,
>   proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=169.55.16.113
>   cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1}
>   (recycle count=0), exception = java.io.IOException: unexpected end of
>   stream on Connection{macm-rendering.saas.ibmcloud.com:443,
>   proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=169.55.16.113
>   cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1}
>   (recycle count=0)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.ibm.caas.CAASService$RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(CAASService.java:658)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.ibm.caas.CAASService$RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(CAASService.java:617)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.ibm.caas.CAASService$RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(CAASService.java:658) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.ibm.caas.CAASService$RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(CAASService.java:617) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at this post and rephrase what issues you are experiencing. I started to edit it, but I didn't understand some of the sentences.

Comment: sorry i was forgot to add my error logs.